# Writing an array of NSDictionaries to documents?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, foundation

I'm trying to write an NSArray of NSDictionaries to the documents folder. I'm using

```
BOOL fileWritten = [favoritesArray writeToFile:fullFileName atomically:NO];
    if (fileWritten == NO) {
        NSLog(@"Writing favoritesFileFailed");
    }
```

The above keeps returning NO. Any idea why this wouldn't be writing? What's really strange is that this same code was working a few days ago. I read something stating that writeToFile can't handle complex objects. Would NSDictionary be an object writeToFile can't save?

Comment: What your dictionaries create? What keys dictionaries use? Is file path correct?

Comment: What objects do the NSDictionary objects contain? I believe it's perfectly fine to archive Arrays and Dictionaries, but if they contain a non-arhivable object then that is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing the `NSDictionary` itself to a file is not a problem, but the objects it holds may be.

By using the simple property list-related I/O methods, you can write out objects of classes `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, and any combination thereof (e.g., arrays of dictionaries).

Also, it won't overwrite an existing file, so have you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

Yeh if you have got custom objects i would do some NSCoding magic and then you can use `[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:favoritesArray]`

So you need to make sure each custom class within that array conforms to `NSCoding` [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

First check that the `fullFileName` actually points to the documents directory.

Then remember that `[NSArray: writeToFile:atomically:]` can only write datatypes that can be saved in a plist file: NSString, NSData, NSDictionary and NSArray - and those will be validated recursively!

Answer (score 0):

Try saving a simple array with a simple object. Perhaps one that only has a number, and see if the problem persists. If it doesn't then the objects in the array are probably something to consider saving somewhere else.

Have you tried saving it to `NSUserDefaults`? Why not try that if all else fails?